# How to execute an update query while MysqlDataReader is running

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using C# console app to update a table with a lot of rows based on the value of two column inside MySQL. 
Below is the code that I've tried to update the table. 
Is it possible to execute update during dataread while loop or do I need to use other way to accomplish this?

```
int currentPoints;
int shudhavePoints;
string email;
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT user_email, meta_value AS 'Current Points',  point FROM wp_usermeta", con);
MySqlDataReader rdr = null;
rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

if(rdr.HasRows)
{
    while(rdr.Read())
    {           
        email = rdr.GetString(0);

        currentPoints = Int32.Parse(rdr.GetString(1));

        shudhavePoints = Int32.Parse(rdr.GetString(2));
        if (currentPoints>shudhavePoints)
        { 
            // I want to update here 
            MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE TABLE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = @cp WHERE user_email = @email", con);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cp", shudhavePoints);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",email);
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("I read nothing!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Right now if I execute the programs, the data will not be updated and will show error

> 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.'

However if I close the connection, it will only execute and update the very first row which satisfy the if-else rule.
I think there must be a way for this to run in a loop without having me to run the program repeating times. 
Can anyone suggest how should I fix the code for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can define new connection object for that

```
int currentPoints;
int shudhavePoints;
string email;
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnectionString"].Connection
String);
MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnectionString"].Connection
String);
con.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT user_email, meta_value AS 'Current Points',  point FROM wp_usermeta", con);
MySqlDataReader rdr = null;
rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

if(rdr.HasRows)
{
    while(rdr.Read())
    {           
        email = rdr.GetString(0);

        currentPoints = Int32.Parse(rdr.GetString(1));

        shudhavePoints = Int32.Parse(rdr.GetString(2));
        if (currentPoints>shudhavePoints)
        { 
            // I want to update here 
            MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE TABLE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = @cp WHERE user_email = @email", con1);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cp", shudhavePoints);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",email);
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("I read nothing!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int currentPoints;
    int shudhavePoints;
    string email;
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT user_email, meta_value AS 'Current Points',  point FROM wp_usermeta", con);
    MySqlDataReader rdr = null;
    rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

    if(rdr.HasRows)
    {
        while(rdr.Read())
        {

            email = rdr.GetString(0);

            currentPoints = Int32.Parse(rdr.GetString(1));

            shudhavePoints = Int32.Parse(rdr.GetString(2));
            if (currentPoints>shudhavePoints)
            { 
    //I want to update here 
                MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE TABLE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = @cp WHERE user_email = @email", con);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cp", shudhavePoints);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",email);
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

           if(!rdr.read())
             {
                Console.WriteLine("Update query not working!!!");
             }
           else
             {
                //user_email
                string usermail = Convert.ToString(user_email);                   
                usermail  = rdr[0].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("Username: {0}", usermail.ToString());

                //meta_value AS 'Current Points'
                string metavalue = Convert.ToString(meta_value);                   
                metavalue  = rdr[1].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("metavalue: {0}", metavalue.ToString());

                //meta_value AS 'point'
                string points  = Convert.ToString(point);                   
                points  = rdr[2].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("point: {0}", points.ToString());

                Console.ReadLine();
             }

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I read nothing!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Im not sure if this additional code can help me to accomplish what i wanted to ask. The problem now is that I cannot update my database because sql connection (read) should be closed before i can make a new update query (to set point=pointshudhave). let say i close the sql connection (read), I'll need to reopen the program so that it will crawl through the rows to find point>point shudhave again and update.

Comment: Couly you please edit your answer and stress out what is the proposed change?